# make android provide any request to symfony

Tags: android, json, symfony

My project is in symfony where I need to get some data from android. So I implemented json encoding on both parts but my web application does not receive the data from android. I found the android is being unable to send data to symfony..

The code for android where the web link is written is as follows:

```
 JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://external.apostle.digibiz.com/web/app_dev.php/api/test", params);
```

What is the error ??

Comment: you are trying to send a post request  ?

Comment: yes sure..do i have any other option for requesting the data?

Comment: I am not sure about the method that you are using in android side.
This link may help you.http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php") this statement is compatible with any general php webservice. Will this need to be changed for symfony???

Comment: yes any general web service has a url , Nothing will change in a Symfony project